# Splidejs on drag select index

Tags: javascript, typescript, drag, splidejs

State:
splidejs component with 24 slides,
only 3 slides appear to user,
focus: 'center'

Problem:
After user drag slides, property index (of selected slide) still indicates to old invisible slide.

Question:
How change selected index of visible slide (in center) after drag?

Any help will be apricate.

Answer (score 0):

### If you're using vanilla JS approach

This thread should give you the required information: https://github.com/Splidejs/splide/issues/227

### If you're using Vue

I've made a few changes to the solution in the thread above.


The template includes the `active` and `resize` events:

```
<Splide
    ref="slider"
    @splide:active="updateHeight"
    @splide:resize="updateHeight"
>...</Splide>
```

Then, add a `currentSlideIndex` to your `data` and fire the `updateHeight` event on component mount:

```
data() {
    return {
        currentSlideIndex: 0
    }
},
mounted() {
    this.updateHeight();
},
```

Finally, include the `updateHeight` method itself. It takes the `currentSlideIndex` from data and updates it only if the slide has been changed (during the `active` event). Since the slide doesn't change on component mount and on resize, we're using the saved `currentSlideIndex` value in this case. After that, we find the slide by index, get its height and update the height of the container (i.e. the `splide__list` element).

```
methods: {
    updateHeight(newSlide) {
        if (newSlide) {
            this.currentSlideIndex = newSlide.index
        }

        const slide = this.$refs.slider.splide.Components.Slides.getAt(this.currentSlideIndex).slide
        slide.parentElement.style.height = slide.offsetHeight + 'px'
    }
}
```

If anyone has suggestions on how to improve this solution, I'd be happy to change it accordingly.